# What are sites tracking software bugs/defects?

Tags: tracking

I am looking for websites which have list of 'real life' software bugs from software (OS software, application software, ... it can be any layer). It could be open-source or it can be code under any other model of development.  Basically I am interested in finding out sites which allow me to read code snippets which have bugs in it. Programming languages interested are C,C++,PERL. But if the s/w defects are language agnostic, and more to do with general concepts(or misuse of them rather), then it still would be helpful.

P.S. To check out 'bugzilla' or bug tracking links for each open-source project for this is one way.

(BTW what is the url for bug tracking in Linux development(kernel related bugs, device driver related, networking layer related,...)

Any pointers would be useful.

Thank you,
-AD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few that come to mind:

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=bugs
- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/
- the issue tracker on any github project. I think it's just https://github.com/[username]/[project name]/issues
- similarly for any Google Code project. http://code.google.com/p/[project name]/issues (the Android one has a zillion bugs)
- The linux kernel is hosted at kernel.org I believe, so click around there and you will most likely find a bug tracker.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with "meta" bug trackers, such as [bugs.debian.org](http://www.debian.org/Bugs/). This tracks bugs of all Debian packages, spanning many open source projects.